# Rows won't filter past the inserted table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a sheet, I had to cut off the data as of a certain date (the bottom total row) but then continue counting from that cut off date (another totals row added, new bottom totals row).

In order to keep the totals from changing when/if someone decides to sort any column, I inserted a table (just 1 row) to keep the totals (formulas) unchanged.

But now when we filter any column it only includes the data up to the inserted totals table/row, so it won't filter any from rows below the table.

Any suggestions? I'm a novice so laymans terms help, I have scoured Google for an answer to no avail.

Comment: I believe when you set a filter then it is only for those rows and any new rows will not be included (this is not true for tables). So, you just have to clear the filters and then reapply them.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing things its hard to say for sure, but the row you inserted it is completely empty?  One quick thing that might help is enter something like an x in one of the cells. it might suggest to Excel that all the data if part of the same table and your filters might start working again. If you don't want this entry to show up visually, change it's colour to match the background colour of the cell (likely white).

I hope this helps,
Brad

Comment: Thanks, the table does have data in almost all the rows, still nothing. For example Row 2 has all the headers that the filters are added to, row 3-10 has the years 1990 &1991(mixed up) entered, then row 11 is the table, then row 12 has the year 1991. If i filter that column to just show year 1990, row 12 will still shop up (1991) Yikes hope that makes sense lol

Comment: The key if you want your Filter to work there has to be at least one cell with data in it , in every row. Otherwise Excel will generally believe the table has ended at the row with no data.